# How to disable javascript programmatically

Tags: internet-explorer, registry

I can disable java script in internet security in IE. But how do I do it programmatically? Like using registry keys?

Comment: Probably yes, but the registry is not something you could access via an arbitrary web page.

Comment: No.  There is no documented API for updating the user's local settings.  Further, this would be complicated by user account control and other integrity protections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you can do it like this -

```
private void UpdateDataSource()      
    {         
        RegistryKey ChangeSettings = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\3", true); 

        // "Active Scripting" - "Disable"          
        ChangeSettings.SetValue("1400", "3", RegistryValueKind.DWord);          

        ChangeSettings.Close();    
    }
```

//------ Or Using Simple Command in CommandPrompt ------//

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3" /t REG_DWORD /v 1400 /d 3 /f
```

**Note :** To enable use -> /d 0 in CommandPrompt

OR

"1400", "0"    in C#

Answer (score 0):

In VBA can do like this :

```
sub tst()
    Dim wsh As IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell
    Set wsh = New IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell
    wsh.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersi\Internet Settings\Zones\3\1400", "0", "REG_DWORD"
end sub()
```